# Curious Case of Polybag Sold Separately in ~2003

Tags: set-identification

I am currently in the middle of my long Dark Age and I am trying to identify the polybag that was sold separately in Poland around year 2003. It had a number, airholes, LEGO logo and yellow accents, it contained assorted, mostly useless (including non-matching) parts in weird colors.

I am absolutely sure these were inside and I know for a fact that parts differed slightly on bag to bag basis. It looks like these were excess throw-away parts.

1x [4204: Brick 8x16 - Dark Gray](https://rebrickable.com/parts/4204/brick-8-x-16/8/)
3x [41748pr0020: Wedge Curved 6x2 Left with 3 Ovals Print](https://rebrickable.com/parts/41748pr0020/wedge-curved-6-x-2-left-with-3-ovals-print/)
3x [30144pr0015: Brick 2x4x3 with Octan Print - White](https://rebrickable.com/parts/30144pr0015/brick-2-x-4-x-3-with-octan-print/15/)
1x [30144: Brick 2x4x3 - Tan](https://rebrickable.com/parts/30144/brick-2-x-4-x-3/19/)

Can somebody kindly shed some light on it, what was that and why would they even sell such things? For the record I have never had any of the sets in which these parts were originally used (according to Rebrickable).

Comment: By "airholes" you are referring to a type of old polybags which were used to package bricks in sets during 90's?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't exactly recall the polybags from the 90s, I just mean that its surface was perforated with tiny holes. I remember because it felt differently right away.

Comment: I remember them as well - I just think they're reasonable inside a box, where eyes look not and fingers poke not, but by themselves, would be too prone to abuse by shoppers. I have to assume it was done because they made it much easier to fit everything in a box, because Lego wouldn't have to suck or squeeze air out of a sealed bag - it would just get squished out naturally.

Answer (score 4):

Air holes always seem dangerous when there's a possibility of small Lego pieces that could be forced through.

North American Lego stores used to sell these bags, but stopped in roughly 2010 due to health concerns regarding sanitizing (so I was told). They were, as yours were, just leftover bricks. I realize they don't match your description of air holes or a number, but thought they might jog someone's memory.

[image: front][image: back]

Comment: Thank you, at least I am not imagining things :), I remember I found it really curious  that LEGO would delibarately sell sth like this (I was 12yo). Yours look idd a bit similar to what I remember. It was a small, bizarre store with surprising amount of licensed LEGO products (which was rare in my country back then), I also remember buying 635 Extra Bricks in White there.